# Pi asks for login when remotely accessing it

Tags: raspbian, update, login

I've been using a Raspberry Pi for 1 year maybe more. I installed Raspbian on it and I use it as a media center among other things.

Recently I accessed it via SSH and ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I then shut off the client.

Now the Pi asks me for a password that is not the default, user: pi, password: raspberry.

[image]

I tried using other sessions, like `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`, and I can log in. How can I access the default xsession again?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another user and see if the default configuration (automatically copied from `/etc/skel`) for that user allows you to log in. These commands will create a user named `user59347` and allow you to specify a password from the command line (`<ctrl>+<alt>+<F1>` or other terminal window):

```
sudo useradd user59347 && sudo passwd user59347
```

If you can log into that account, something is wrong with your configuration files in `/home/pi`